# Prestashop : Custom CSS not working on Mozilla

Tags: css, prestashop, mozilla

My prestashop boutique is working fine on Chrome and Opera but some elements come out all wrong on Mozilla.

Indeed, I edited the CSS so that the product list would look like this :

[image]

But on Mozilla, the custom classes and ids don't even show and the results is all broken.

[image]

Comment: a link to your shop would be helpfull tro troubleshoot that issue.
but for now you can check "caniuse.com" to check whether the browser is supporting your css or not.

Comment: I'm working local, unfortunately I can't. I'll update this thread when I find the cause.

Comment: Show us some piece of code

Comment: I fixed it, it was the function "Sort By" that wasn't edited on Mozilla.